# Angular: Property not found tap but is in normal subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

I am trying to use debounce time and I am getting a strange typescript error. I can use value.searchSting in the normal subscription, but with the piped description I use tap and I get an error saying `Property 'searchString' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

What am I doing wrong. I'm sure tap should be fine with this.

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe( value => console.log(value.searchString)); // No errors
```

This works fine, no red underline under value.searchString

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap(value => {

     
    console.log(value.searchString); // Underlined Typescript error
    
      let searchTerm = value.searchString; // Underlined Typescript error

      this.filteredUserNames = this.users.filter((userName) =>
        userName.searchTerms
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
  })
).subscribe();
```

Typescript is not happy and underlines value.searchString here and gives the above error. Very strange. What am I doing wrong and is there a workaround.

Comment: check what is the type of `value` in `tap`

Comment: Its the form object: { searchString: "" }

Comment: have you tried `value:any` inside `tap` like `tap((value:any) => {`

Comment: how do you defined ```myForm```?

Comment: this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      searchString: [""],
    });

Comment: Yeah, it's ok. And, what happens if instead of consuming your search term in the ```tap``` function you process it in the subscription, I mean: ```subscribe((searchTerm) => {})```. Does typescript report any error? You can also process the information in that way

Comment: No not in the subscription no. That is why it is weird.

Comment: Even with the debounce and distinctUntilChange function? I mean: ```this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe((value) => console.log(value.searchString));```

Comment: Apologies. But no no error in there.

Comment: I see, an it is right. And it works in other components? The exact code? By the way, perhaps consuming the search term in the subscription could be a better way to go: it will allow you, for instance, to ```takeUntil(something onDestroy)``` and stop the observable.

Comment: Please, place a ```tap``` as the first operator of the ```pipe```and then right after every other operator - debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged```: it may provide you some inside about what is going on

Comment: @jccampanero Thank you for your efforts. I can't really spend any more time on this but I like your idea of consuming the searchTerm in the subscription. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not mentioned the type of **value** object. Just mention it as an **any** object. Something like this

```
tap((value:any) => {

 
console.log(value.searchString); // Underlined Typescript error

  let searchTerm = value.searchString; // Underlined Typescript error

  this.filteredUserNames = this.users.filter((userName) =>
    userName.searchTerms
      .toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
  })
```

Comment: I have this working perfectly with exactly the same code in a different component without the need to apply the type to the value in tap. Something strange is going on in my component as in others no type declaration is needed.

Comment: This does have the code working so answers the question but I would still like to know why this time I had to supply the type when other times I do not.

Comment: Typescript can inherently understand the data types of basic types e.g. string, number, boolean. In case of objects it can get confused. Also the context of usage matter as well.

Comment: So for example, if I have somethink like httpClient.get<any>("someurl").pipe(tap(res=>{})); the code already knows the res object is of type any, because its apparent.